# what is the PHP equivalent for API Python's requests package

Tags: php, api

I am trying to replicate the same json request in php from this Python code:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard'
payload = {
    'limit':'500',
    'groups':'8'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
```

I know how to curl a API request in php but not sure the sythanx for the parameter input, in this case , 'limit' & 'groups'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. Just in case you're curious why I removed the Python tag, I explained my rationale [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413747/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `http_build_query()` to convert the array of parameters to URL query parameters, then concatenate it to the URL.

`file_get_contents()` is the simple equivalent to `requests.get()` if you don't need to provide any custom headers.

```
$payload = [
    'limit' => 500,
    'groups' => 8
];
$params = http_build_query($payload);
$url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard?' . $params;
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($result, true);
```